# Select statement using ORM Axon in the php F3 framework

Tags: php, mysql, fat-free-framework

I am brand new to the Fat-Free-Framework F3 for PHP
I am trying to build a blog
I have a simple query

```
'SELECT * FROM blogs  ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 5'
```

I want to build this query using the Axon ORM that is built in to the F3 framework

In my thinking I want to try this:

```
     $blogs = new Axon('blogs');
     $blogs->load(array('limit'=>5, 'order by'=>'created', 'order'=>'DESC'));
```

Is this the correct way?
Does anyone know of any good Axon documentation?

Thanks

Comment: I would except this is for my work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will do it.  You can loop through $posts as Axon objects now.

```
$blogs = new Axon('blogs');
$posts = $blogs->find('','created DESC',5);
```

While Fatfree seems simple and easy, it pales in comparison to what is out there.